# After installing NestJS 8.0.1 >> NestJS Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the (controller name)

Tags: nestjs

full error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommitteesController (?). 
Please make sure that the argument CommitteesService at index [0] is available in the CommitteesModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If CommitteesService is a provider, is it part of the current CommitteesModule?
- If CommitteesService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CommitteesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing CommitteesService */ ]
  })

at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (C:\Sites\AM-API-MDD\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:193:19)
at async Injector.resolveComponentInstance (C:\Sites\AM-API-MDD\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:149:33)
```

This was working with NestJS 7.6, but I upgraded the version to 8.0.1 and started getting this error.

There are several other modules that don't get an error, however, this is the first module in the list. The processor may not get to the other modules after returning this error.

committees.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from '../database';
import { defaultIncludeQuery, PER_PAGE_COUNT } from './constant';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class CommitteesService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  committees() { 
    return Promise.all([
      this.prisma.committee.findMany({
        include: {
          PersonCommittee: {
            include: {
              Person: {
                select: {
                  PKPersonID: true,
                  LastName: true,
                  FirstName: true,
                  MiddleName: true,
                  PreferredFirstName: true,
                  DisplayName: true,
                  EmploymentStatus: true
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        },
        where: {
          Active: true,
          OR: [
            { PersonCommittee: { some: { Person: { EmploymentStatus: 'A' } } } },
            { PersonCommittee: { some: { Person: { EmploymentStatus: 'B' } } } },
            { PersonCommittee: { some: { Person: { EmploymentStatus: 'C' } } } },
          ],
        }
      })
    ])
  }
```

committees.controller.ts

```
import {
  Body,Controller,DefaultValuePipe,Delete,Get,Param,ParseIntPipe,Post,Put,Query,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommitteesService } from './committees.service';
import { RESOURCE_BASE_ROUTE } from '../constant';
import { PER_PAGE_COUNT } from './constant';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const Route = RESOURCE_BASE_ROUTE.committees;

@Controller()
export class CommitteesController {
  constructor(private readonly committeesService: CommitteesService) {}

  @Get(`${Route}`)
  all() {
    return this.committeesService.committees();
  }

  @Get(`${Route}/:id`)
  byId(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    if ( id == -1 ) {
      return this.committeesService.committees()
    }
    return this.committeesService.committee({
      CommitteeID: id,
    });
  }
```

committees.modules.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { CommitteesController } from './committees.controller';
import { CommitteesService } from './Committees.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [CommitteesController],
  providers: [CommitteesService],
  exports: [ CommitteesService],
})
export class CommitteesModule {}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "am-api-mdd",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.10",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.18",
    "node-windows": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.1.2",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.18",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^14.17.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prisma": "^3.1.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: I reinstalled NestJS 7.6.0 and everything works fine.

Comment: I think this happens due to this change: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/6141 but your module `CommitteesModule` looks fine to me

Comment: You might want to make sure that **all** of the Nest dependencies are up to date, and not just `common` and `core`. I see `microservices` and `platform-express` are still down on v7 and rxjs is on v8

Comment: +1 for @JayMcDoniel . With NestJS you should always keep all main packages at the same version. Some symbols can be different between versions and it may lead to issues like this. Try to bump all Nest packages to 8.* and try again

Comment: I did update microservices and platform-express with no joy.